# Fuzzy Vlookup on Pandas

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I have two dataframes with around 300,000 rows and roughly 11 columns each.

The first dataframe contains raw data, with names that are not homogeneous strings. The other has official data (and homogeneous strings). First of all, I tried running a fuzzy matching between the 'raw data' and the official data via a code, which seems to be working well for a dataframe with roughly 200 entries. When I try running the code on my >300,000 rows, the kernel is slower (it's been running for over an hour now)... Any ideas on how I could do speed up this process? I was thinking of splitting the dataframes into smaller ones, but I would need the entire dataset to make sure the matching is correct.

Thanks!

P.S. Current Code:

````
def fuzzy_merge(df_1, df_2, key1, key2, threshold=90, limit=2):
    """
    :param df_1: the left table to join
    :param df_2: the right table to join
    :param key1: key column of the left table
    :param key2: key column of the right table
    :param threshold: how close the matches should be to return a match, based on Levenshtein distance
    :param limit: the amount of matches that will get returned, these are sorted high to low
    :return: dataframe with boths keys and matches
    """
    s = df_2[key2].tolist()

    m = df_1[key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s, limit=limit))    
    df_1['Example1'] = m

    m2 = df_1['CompanyName'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i[0] for i in x if i[1] >= threshold]))
    df_1['Example2'] = m2

    return df_1

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

merged_df = fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, 'Example1', 'Example2', threshold=90)
print(merged_df)```
````

Comment: Could you share your current code?

Comment: Shared! I took the fuzzywuzzy code from another stack overflow post.

Comment: Be aware that this is going to be a long-running task anyways, string comparisons are expensive computationally and you're doing a LOT of them. My approach is usually to first identify subsets that can just be matched against each other to drastically speed things up.

Comment: @maxbachmann, what about running this other fuzzymatcher library? 
fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, left_on, right_on)? Without calculating the Levenshtein distance.

Comment: @Oso one thing I already do inside my library rapidfuzz is to return early when I am sure the score can not be reached. This is done first by comparing the string lengths in constant time and then afterwards by counting uncommon characters between the two strings in linear time, so the actual levenshtein distance (quadratic time) does not has to be calculated each time.

Comment: @maxbachmann clever! I'll have to take a look at it for my next datasource consolidation task.

Answer (score 1):

Given your task your comparing 300k strings with 300k different strings. You end up with a total of 90 billion comparisions, with each of these comparisions using the levenshtein distance inside fuzzywuzzy which is a O(N*M) operation. Thats why this operation will never be very fast. However it is possible to perform this matching faster with a couple of changes:

1. use [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz) instead of FuzzyWuzzy, since it implements the same algorithm, but is a lot faster
2. RapidFuzz allows to pass a `score_cutoff` to `process.extract`. This way it only returns matches above this score and can often skip bad matches very fast
3. the strings in s are currently preprocessed by fuzz.extract multiple times. It is faster to do this only once.

The following code applies these changes to your code:

```py
from rapidfuzz import process, utils as fuzz_utils

def fuzzy_merge(df_1, df_2, key1, key2, threshold=90, limit=2):
    s_mapping = {x: fuzz_utils.default_process(x) for x in df_2[key2]}

    m1 = df_1[key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(
      fuzz_utils.default_process(x), s_mapping, limit=limit, score_cutoff=threshold, processor=None
    ))    
    df_1['CompanyName'] = m1

    m2 = df_1['CompanyName'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(i[2] for i in x))
    df_1[key2] = m2

    return df_1

merged_df = fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, 'Example1', 'Example2', threshold=90)
```

The changes gave me around a 20x speed improvement, but this will vary depending on your data